# How to remove newline when importing csv file c#

Tags: csv, newline, streamreader, readline

I have a csv file that I would to import to sharepoint list. My issue is that some lines are broken to new row. 
For example.

( This how it looks when open the file with excel)

**Name, Email, country, City, zip code**

when importing it, the script splits the above to **2** lines:

**Name Email Country**

**City zip code**

```
   using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\doc\myfile.csv"))
        {
            string line;
            int counter = 0;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
```

Please help

Comment: Have a look at Trim()

Comment: Does your csv file have multiline fields?